# TypeError (nil can't be coerced into Float):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im trying to implement ratings system. Going through [this tutorial](http://camjuarez.com/posts/star-rating-system-with-ajax-and-remote-forms)

I keep getting this error when i try to give a rating:

```
Started PATCH "/ratings/7.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-31 14:09:58 +0200
Processing by RatingsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"j/bCg3mFtQLl1n5qSZInNrUoKaRT/PKpzLnEz6QNGcQ=", "rating"=>{"book_id"=>"1", "user_id"=>"1", "stars"=>"4"}, "id"=>"7"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rating Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books"  WHERE "books"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rating Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "ratings".* FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."book_id" = $1  [["book_id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms

TypeError (nil can't be coerced into Float):
  app/models/book.rb:30:in `+'
  app/models/book.rb:30:in `block in avg_rating'
  app/models/book.rb:29:in `avg_rating'
  app/controllers/ratings_controller.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in update'
  app/controllers/ratings_controller.rb:35:in `update'
```

My show.html.erb view:

```
<% form_id = "book_#{@book.id}_rating" %>
<% if user_signed_in? %> <!-- To avoid throwing an exception if no user is signed in -->
    <% user_id = current_user.id %>
<% else %>
    <% user_id = -1 %>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @book.ratings.find_or_create_by(user_id: user_id), :html => {:id => form_id, :class => "star_rating_form"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, :value => @book.id %>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :stars, :id => form_id + "_stars" %>
<% end %>
<% (1..5).each do |i| %>
    <li class="rating_star" id="<%= form_id %>_<%= i %>" data-stars="<%= i %>" data-form-id="<%= form_id %>"></li>
<% end %>
```

My ratings_controller.rb:

```
  before_filter :js_logged_in

  def create
    @rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
    @book = Book.find(params[:rating][:book_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rating.save
        format.json { render :json => { :avg_rating => @book.avg_rating } }
      else
        format.json { render :json => @rating.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @rating = Rating.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rating.update_attributes(rating_params)
        format.json { render :json => { :avg_rating => @rating.book.avg_rating } }
      else
        format.json { render :json => @rating.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def js_logged_in
    if(!user_signed_in?)
      flash[:error] = "You must be a signed in to leave a rating!"
      render :js => "window.location = '/users/sign_in'"
    end
  end

  private

  def rating_params

    params.require(:rating).permit(:book_id, :stars, :user_id)

  end
```

My book.rb model:

```
  def avg_rating
    average_rating = 0.0
    count = 0
    ratings.each do |rating|
      average_rating += rating.stars
      count += 1
    end

    if count != 0
      (average_rating / count)
    else
      count
    end
  end
```

my rating.rb model:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessor :stars
end
```

anyone has a clue - why this doesn't work?

Comment: In your model you have to make sure that `rating.stars` is not `nil`. Your getting this error because `rating.stars` is nil for one of your object in `ratings` array. To overcome the problem you could do something like this `average_rating += rating.stars.to_f`. This will convert `nil` to `0.0` so your code stays intact and you don't run through issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of your ratings' `stars` attribute returns `nil`. So when you call `average_rating += rating.stars`, which is equivalent to `average_rating = average_rating + nil`, you get an error. If `nil` value in this field means `0`, you should probably have:

```
average_rating += rating.stars || 0
```

If `nil` value is undesirable in this field, you should validate it in `Rating` model:

```
validates_presence_of :stars
```

Also, since `stars` is a field in your `ratings` table, you don't need `attr_accessor :stars` in `Rating` model.

Comment: Well, this doesn't raise an error. But the rating that is written in the DB is 0.

Comment: @AndreiCirnici in all ratings? What does `Rating.where(stars: nil).count` returns?

Comment: 2.1.3 :053 > Rating.where(stars: nil).count
   (69.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."stars" IS NULL
 => 0

Comment: Ok, that's strange. Try to debug it, with `pry` for example. Add `gem pry` into your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` and in the code add
`binding.pry if rating.stars.nil?` before this line. Then run the code and investigate the issue.

Comment: models/book.rb @ line 31 Book#avg_rating:
    26: def avg_rating
    27: 
    28:   average_rating = 0.0
    29:   count = 0
    30:   ratings.each do |rating|
 => 31:     binding.pry if rating.stars.nil?
    32:     average_rating += rating.stars || 0
    33:     count += 1
    34:   end
    35: 
    36:   if count != 0
    37:     (average_rating / count)
    38:   else
    39:     count
    40:   end
    41: end

[1] pry(#<Book>)> rating
=> #<Rating id: 7, stars: 0, book_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-10-31 12:09:16">
[2] pry(#<Book>)> rating.stars
=> nil

Comment: @AndreiCirnici Now I know why this happens. Remove `attr_accessor :stars` from `Rating` model class.